# Как разворачивать базу данных

Tags: база-данных, docker, развертывание

Изучаю docker

Везде вижу одну и ту же инфу, что бд не стоит разворачивать в контейнере, но нигде почему-то не говорят как ее лучше разворачивать.

Допустим у меня есть бэкенд+брокер+sql+redis. Чтобы првильно все развернуть следует все кроме бэкенда разворачивать на локальной машине, а бэкенд можно развернуть в docker пробросив порты?

Я думал про то чтобы развернуть в отдельном образе sql и все клиентские данные хранить в этом образе, чтобы легко мигрировать бд вместе с данными на другие машины

Я знаю что технически все можно развернуть в docker, но вопрос в том, как сделать парвильнее.

Comment: Скорее всего имелось в виду, что саму базу с данными нужно вольюмом подключать, а не внтури контейнера держать.

Comment: @CrazyElf неоднократно видел заявления, что база должна быть без контейнеров вообще совсем (хотя обоснование тоже не знаю)

Comment: @andreymal Ну вот есть небольшая дискуссия, например https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/what-are-the-reasons-docker-should-not-be-used-for-databases

Comment: @CrazyElf вот как раз в первом абзаце первого ответа говорится как раз о том что я и описал. Держать базу  в образе но не в контейнере. Получается в образе будет уже сконфигурированная бд и данные которые прилетают и прилетали от пользователей. Получается образ будет разрастаться. Получается, для миграции на другую физическую машину, нужно просто запушить образ с бд в докер хаб, установить этот образ на другую машину, запустить образ. Все конфиги и данные клиентов сохранятся. Получается так можно делать...